# Ruby/Rails - Converting an integer into a float excluding existing zeros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There must be a simple way to achieve this, I have an DB field containing an integer and I want to reformat it into a float to display.

As an integer my value looks like `6500` and I want it to display as `65.00`

Within my model I have attempted to achieve this by creating the following method

```
def get_payment_amount_as_number
  amount = self.payment_amount
  return '%.02f' % self.payment_amount.to_f
end
```

Which results in the following being displayed: `6500.00`

What would the best approach be to either strip the initial zeroes or to simply insert a decimal point?

Whilst I imagine this a ruby related question, I am not sure if rails has a handy helper already in place?

Thank you.

Comment: Just divide it by 100

Comment: Absolutely correct. If you wish to post it as an answer I can accept it! Sometimes its easy to over complicate the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could divide the number by 100:

```
payment_amount = 6595

'%.02f' % payment_amount.fdiv(100)
#=> "65.95"

'%.02f' % (payment_amount / 100.0)
#=> "65.95"
```

Or you could convert the number to a string and insert a decimal point:

```
payment_amount.to_s.rjust(3, '0').insert(-3, '.')
#=> "65.95"
```

Rails also provides several [helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper.html) to format numbers:

```
number_to_currency(65.95)
#=> "$65.95"

number_to_currency(1000)
#=> "$1,000.00"
```

And you might want to take a look at the [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) gem which provides a mapping from cents to [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) objects.

Answer (score 1):

You do this simply ...

```
def get_payment_amount_as_number
  amount = self.payment_amount / 100
  #to convert amount to float
  amount.to_f
end
```

I find another one

```
amount = self.payment_amount
# => 6500
ans = '%.2f' % (amount/100)
# => "65.00"
```

Comment: That would truncate the cents and it would return `65.0` instead of `"65.00"`

Answer (score 0):

```
int_value = 6500
float_value = float_value = '%.2f' % (int_value / 100.0)
puts int_value: int_value, float_value: float_value
```

it's all!